# Grouping minutes by time intervals

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

If I were using Oracle, this issue would be resolved in a few minutes using rank over functions, however, not something that orientdb has, or is in it's roadmap.

I currently have a requirement, to do avg on a property and the group data by time intervals at the minute level.

Taking a 15 minute time span which gives me 15 records / 1 record per minute, I need to be able to group the data in intervals of 5 Minutes

**My data structure is as follows**[image]

**My end results should be something like**

> avg(Last).............|..... GroupedMinutes
>
> ---
>
> 0.00103445 ....... |......5
>
> 0.00103441 ....... |......10
>
> 0.0010344 ......... |......15

**Sample Data**

```
create class times
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049611',7,29,19,0)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049634',7,29,19,1)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049654',7,29,19,2)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049660',7,29,19,3)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049655',7,29,19,4)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049654',7,29,19,5)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049677',7,29,19,6)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049654',7,29,19,7)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049698',7,29,19,8)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049687',7,29,19,9)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049633',7,29,19,10)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049622',7,29,19,11)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049643',7,29,19,12)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049634',7,29,19,13)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049657',7,29,19,14)
insert into times (exe, Last, month, day, hour, minute) values ('EXE','0.1049698',7,29,19,15)
```

Comment: Maybe by means of a javascript function, you can create it. The function generate a query that retrieves the data every tot minutes (for example, 5 minutes from a start_time to a end_time) and returns the [average -- group].

Comment: Thanks, that is my current path of development. However, I wanted to know if there's something at the DB level to facilitate the challenge.

Answer (score 4):

I quickly wrote a js function that might help you get started, bear in mind that it's not optimized as it doesn't calculate the averages between different days:

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
var query = g.command("SQL", "SELECT * FROM times ORDER BY month, day, hour, minute");

var avg = 0, group = 0;
var prev_month, prev_day, prev_hour, prev_minute;
var record = [];

for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i++)
{
    var month = query[i].getRecord().field("month").toString();
    var day = query[i].getRecord().field("day").toString();
    var hour = query[i].getRecord().field("hour").toString();
    var minute = parseInt(query[i].getRecord().field("minute").toString());

    if((minute == (prev_minute + 1) && day == prev_day && hour == prev_hour && month == prev_month) || i == 0)
    {
        avg += parseFloat(query[i].getRecord().field("Last").toString());
        group++;

        if(group >= 5 || group >= (query.length-i)+2)
        {
            record.push((avg / group).toString().substring(0,11));
            avg = 0;
            group = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        record.push((avg / group).toString().substring(0,11));
        avg = 0;
        group = 0;

        avg += parseFloat(query[i].getRecord().field("Last").toString());
        group++;

        if(group >= (query.length-i)+2)
        {
            record.push((avg / group).toString().substring(0,11));
            avg = 0;
            group = 0;
        }
    }

    prev_month = month;
    prev_day = day;
    prev_hour = hour;
    prev_minute = minute;
}

return record;
```